# Magento - Child theme starting point

Tags: php, magento, xampp, themes

I've recently started to learn Magento (very recently) - and I followed this link to get started on XAMPP https://magenticians.com/install-magento-2-on-localhost-using-xampp/

I now have a localhost setup of XAMPP, and would like to start making changes to the site. I have read that you need to create a 'child-theme' but really unsure of where to start on this.

I can see 2 themes at C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma 
but can't see any at C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend

Does anyone have a pointer in the right direction? or even a version with populated content/a child theme ready to edit?

Sorry and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you need follwing file for making child theme

```
app> design> forntend> <Vendor> / <Theme_Child> /
```

1- `composer.json` (optional in case parent have)

2- `registration.php`

3- media folder  (with preview image)

4- `Magento_Theme`

5- etc

6- `view.xml`